# Dataframe made by grouped columns, then calculating the mean of those groups: how to color by one of the variables in the columns used to group?

Tags: python, graph

I generated a dataframe generated from variables from columns grouped together, and by calculating the mean of those groups. I can make a bar chart of the full data frame, but don't know how to colour by one of the variables in the columns used to group? For example, this is my grouped dataframe as it prints in the console of python:

```
                                nWW         nDW
Treatment Wavelength Line                        
0         Au 242.795 OE3   177.729631  177.729631
                     WT    146.940092  146.940092
          Au 267.595 OE3   253.899473  253.899473
                     WT    214.758596  214.758596
          Cu         OE3   330.069314  330.069314
                     WT    282.577100  282.577100
          Pd 340.458 OE3   104.168031  104.168031
                     WT     79.121588   79.121588
          Pd 342.124 OE3    25.389947   25.389947
                     WT     11.303084   11.303084
10ppm Au  Au 242.795 OE3   195.173963  195.173963
                     WT    184.447764  184.447764
          Au 267.595 OE3   260.231951  260.231951
                     WT    249.546975  249.546975
          Cu         OE3   325.289939  325.289939
                     WT    314.646186  314.646186
          Pd 340.458 OE3   130.115976  130.115976
                     WT    119.348553  119.348553
          Pd 342.124 OE3    65.057988   65.057988
                     WT     54.249342   54.249342
10ppm Pd  Au 242.795 OE3   227.210790  227.210790
                     WT    301.110149  301.110149
          Au 267.595 OE3   312.414837  312.414837
                     WT    421.554208  421.554208
          Cu         OE3   397.618883  397.618883
                     WT    541.998267  541.998267
          Pd 340.458 OE3   142.006744  142.006744
                     WT    180.666089  180.666089
          Pd 342.124 OE3   158.017272  158.017272
                     WT     60.222030   60.222030
```

This is the graph generated by the following code:

```
fig = grouped.plot(y='nWW', kind='bar')
```

￼￼[Graph generated using the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uq2T.png)

What I really want to be able to do is colour the bars according to which Line they are, e.g. OE3 or WT, and have those bars stand next to each other without a gap between the OE3 and WT bars in the same condition. I am very much a beginner and have tried and failed to make this work multiple times, and would greatly appreciate some help!